# using std::enable_if on a method of a templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, enable-if

Consider the following code

```
template <class D> class Box {
private:
  D d_;
public:
  Box(D d) : d_(d) {}

  D value() {
    return d_;
  }
  D negate() {
    return -d_;
  }
};
```

I would like the method negate() to only be present/available when D is arithmetic type.   Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it:

```
template <class D> class Box {
private:
  D d_;
public:
  Box(D d) : d_(d) {}

  D value() {
    return d_;
  }

  template< typename T=D >
  typename std::enable_if<is_arithmetic<T>::value, T >::type
    negate() {
    return -d_;
  }
};
```

Comment: Just a FYI, it's still possible to call the function by explicitly giving the template parameter. `Box<std::string>{"wee"}.negate<int>();`

Comment: Which probably can be fixed by adding `&& std::is_same_v<T, D>` to `enable_if`'s condition.